# How to set up an immutable dnslink to IPFS content?

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to achieve the same as these guys did: https://uniswap.org/blog/ipfs-uniswap-interface/

So first I read this:
https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/ipns/

It says:

> IPNS is not the only way to create mutable addresses on IPFS. You can
> also use DNSLink, ...

So I went to read https://dnslink.io/, and then added a TXT `_dnslink` `dnslink=/ipfs/<CID>` entry to my DNS records.

Works perfectly.

But what about an update to content - won't the CID change? Do I have to update the TXT record every time the content changes? Is there a way to have the dnslink record point to always the last release?

https://uniswap.org/blog/ipfs-uniswap-interface/ says:

> That TXT record contains the IPFS hash of the latest release.

So it suggest that it needs to be updated all the time. Maybe there is a programmatic way to update the TXT record so they don't have to go in all the time and change the hash?

Sligthly confused ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

Update the /ipfs/ CID in the TXT every time, programmatically or otherwise. Or, use an /ipns/ CID. With IPNS, you never need to update the TXT, but you need at least 1 IPFS node with the IPNS key to be online most of the time to regularly publish the IPNS record. If you do use IPNS, I recommend generating a new key for the content, not using the default node keypair. This makes it easier to move / copy the key.